# Is there comparative list of snippets that shows how same features are implemented in different js frameworks?

Tags: angularjs, vuejs2

For example:

```
          Vue             Angular
action    v:on            ng-dblclick
          v:bind          ng-bind
```

Or it won't work, because angular is more of a framework and has rigid structure, whereas Vue is mostly a lib according to this article on medium ["angular vs react vs vue"](https://medium.com/unicorn-supplies/angular-vs-react-vs-vue-a-2017-comparison-c5c52d620176)

EDIT: I think it's not subjective question, because it can be answered in "yes\no" manner.

Comment: Good question. I was looking for something like that also.

Comment: @GabMic, hmm I totally did not expect this! thx! I usually expect my questions to be downvoted lol

Comment: @GabMic, this may be a cool hot idea for other web devs! make a list of comparative code snippets - so anyone with "vue" experience can jump start into another framework!

Comment: Hahaha i sure hope someone will come up with this.